# Excel group cells in a table based on their combined total value

Tags: excel

i would like a list of client names where together they have a combined amount of 1000. so, say if jim and tod's combined amount of money <= 1000 and jim, tod, jill >= 1000 then list jim and tod in a cell, then in the next cell if jill, joy, and pat <=1000 and jill, joy, pat, and tam >= 1000 then list jill, joy, and pat and so fourth until all of the clients are in a list. 
[image: image of table]

Is this possible? I am learning and am not sure where to start so i would greatly appreciate if someone can help point me in the right direction to solve this problem?

Comment: For starters:  The way you state your logical parameters is... well... illogical.  Your first sentence doesn't match up with your second.  And your second sentence is trying to combine multiple sets of logic in a long run on sentence.  And none of that logic matches up with the chart you provided.  So... the place to start is to write your specifications in a readable way where each logic point is valid and doesn't contradict other logic points.  That includes knowing how to use > and < signs  with the = sign properly.  Plus, showing what you tried so far wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I see.... language barrier and some mistakes on the less than/ greater than signs. My apologies, I am multilingual and explaining stuff can sometimes get difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your criterion for a group is that the money sums to less than or equal to 1000, then this is straightforward. Simply accumulate the Money amount down the list of names and start a new group and (reset the accumulator) whenever the cumulative amount exceeds 1000.

This gives you the group number for each name (see column `D` in picture below). A separate problem is then to list the names for each group number. In the picture, I have allowed for a maximum of 5 names per group but if real data indicates this is insufficient then allowing more is straightforward.

[image]

The set of groups obtained using this approach is dependent on the ordering of the rows of input data - change this ordering and the result is a different set of groups.

Perhaps a more interesting and challenging problem is to define a set of groups which meet not only the <=1000 criterion but also other criteria such as: minimise number of groups overall and equalise, as far as possible, the total money allocated to each group. But that is a very different problem!

Comment: Thank you so much! I had some mistakes in my logic as I was in the early stage of figuring out how to conceal the actual information but still be able to explain what I am trying to solve.  You were spot on with regard to your interpretation. I agree, my next goal is to minimize the number of groups but i anticipate that it will take me much longer to figure this one out so i needed a temporary solution.